# When should I use Mgmt:addTypoScript , setup.txt and ext_typoscript_setup?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase

The common way to write the TypoScript is in Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt.
But there also two other way to write TS. One with **ext_typoscript_setup.txt** and other with `ExtensionManagementUtility::addTypoScriptSetup()`.

Can someone explain me what the difference is and when should i use which one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theoretically the usage of `ext_typoscript_setup.txt` files has been deprecated. Theoretically because it has never really been removed from the core.

`ext_typoscript_setup.txt` and `ExtensionManagementUtility::addTypoScriptSetup()` do quite the same thing as those will always load the given TypoScript. However the problem is that sometimes people have a hard time overriding those default code. To make it even more complicated there is the select field **Static Template Files from TYPO3 Extensions** inside the sys_template record which can influence the order.

---

As a solution (or at least how I handle it):

Always use the way of having TS in `Configuration/TypoScript/...` and let the integrator decide how and in which order it is included. Some people include TypoScript within their SitePackage, some in sys_template record, ...

However I also use `ext_typoscript_setup.txt` in rare case if some TS must be available and which won't be changed by an integrator.